# Toolbar now showing main AppBar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I am trying to customize the AppBar with a ToolBar, the title and menu area is hidden by the layout that I inject in the toolbar.

The code of my activity layout is this one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bluegrey_300"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="323dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="SOME TEXT" />
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
....
Other components of my activity.
....
```

And here the code of my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ab.setTitle("Title not shown");
```

The undesired result that I get is this:

[image]

Why is the title area not showing? I see it in the design view of AndroidStudio but not on execution.

Comment: What is the title area? What is the desired result that you want to achieve? I see you are nesting component inside Toolbar tag...

Answer (score 0):

use toolbar height like this instead of wrap_content

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
```